# Header div background doesn't repeat

Tags: html, css

Good day to all, I'm having a problem since while with the background of an image http://fishing.gimn-popovo.com/ as you see it doesn't repeat I've tried lots of things but none of them worked. I'd rather say it's a css problem. (Problem is with the header image. I want the background to repeat and continue the old paper structure but it doesn`t)

Comment: You should at least add the CSS code you are using trying to repeat the background

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: 100%` to the inline style of the header image. That should fix things. I don't recommend inline styling but in this case it seems like all your using is inline styling so it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, Try this:

```
#duski {
 background: url(http://fishing.gimn-popovo.com/vajno/old.png);
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 100;
 top: -69px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Remove height and set background-repeat: repeat-x.

HTH.